# Распараллеливание вычислений

Tags: c#

Есть метод, который возводит число в степень:

```
static BigInteger Pow(BigInteger n1, BigInteger n2)
{
    BigInteger res = 1;
    for (ulong i = 0; i < n2; i++)
        res *= n1;

    return res;
}
```

А как теперь его распараллелить? `Parallel.For` не работает с BigInteger

Comment: Для больших чисел распараллеливание с вашим алгоритмом вряд ли поможет. Есть традиционная формула возведения в степень `результат = exp(степень*log(число))`. Вероятно, это как-то можно адаптировать для целых чисел. Экспоненту заменить на двойку в степени, натуральный логарифм на логарифм по основанию два. Тут все равно вылезут числа с точкой, но, **может быть**, это будет все равно быстрее тупо умножения в цикле.

Comment: не надо параллелить, в целую степень можно возвести за log N, это будет быстрее любого параллельного линейного алгоритма